# Multiple data pushes in certain cases in Firebase while attempting one

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node containing certain data within a tree in Firebase. Let's call the root node in this tree as "x". Now when a certain event happens, a part of the children of this node is to be stored at a difference location and the rest deleted. So what I am doing is I have a listener attached to this child node and checking for the value of the node and taking care of the operation. The check, creation of the new node and deletion of the old one is as follows:

```
if(status=="Complete"){
keyAppRef.child(querykey).removeValue()
     val pastkey = oTwoPastRef.push().key
     if(pastkey!=null){
       val hashMap : HashMap<String, String>
                = HashMap<String, String> ()
       hashMap["slot"] = timeslot
       hashMap["chamberTown"] = town
       keyPastRef.child(pastkey).setValue(hashMap)
  }
```

In the above the keyAppRef is the reference to the original node and keyPastRef is the reference to the new node. The variables status, timeslot and town had been obtained from the datasnapshot at keyAppRef and stored through the value event listener earlier. 
Now what happens is instead of one new node being created, multiple nodes get created. I had done a Log.d to find out where the push() command is called by the following:

```
Log.d("MyMessage", "Line 4290 $querykey $pastkey")
```

Strangely when this log command is there just below the push().key command line, there is only one node created. But when again this Log.d command is removed it is back to the same error. Can anyone help what is happening over here.

Has this got something to do with some delay in code process by the Log.d?

Answer (score 0):

After spending a lot of time I could finally find the answer to my own question. Since the situation behaved differently at different times, I could understand that this was a clear case of memory leakage. After I went through the Firebase documentation thoroughly I could understand that the value event listener was having issues with memory leakage as I was not properly removing the listener when the Lifecycle of the app was destroying or stopping. I have now removed the listeners at appropriate places and after that this problem has stopped.